# Scraping data from a website that limits views

Tags: python, networking, web-scraping, ip

So lately I've been working on a passion project of mine that requires thousands of ancient Latin texts and their respective translation.

I found [this website](http://www.latin.it/) which offers them free of charge. Only problem is that if I load a [translation](http://www.latin.it/autore/cesare/de_bello_gallico/!01!liber_i/01.lat) it says "Oggi hai visualizzato 1 brani. Ti ricordiamo che hai ancora a disposizione la visualizzazione di 4 brani" which means that I visualized 1 out of the 4 texts that I'm allowed to see in a day.

What's my best bet? I really want to get this data but since I'm not going to make any money off of it there's no way I can justify paying someone who knows what there doing $400...

Any help would be really appreciated,
thank you

Comment: If it's not against their terms of service, have you tried using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try with the TorBrowser https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en which can change IP when you "reestablish" connection (click the onion next to the url line).

Comment: Unfortunately, Tor doesn't provide a sufficient amount of rotating IP's to accomplish the task.